# inserting a line containing quote mark ' using sed

Tags: bash, sed, insert, character, headless

I am trying script a file that will install VirtualBox Headless. I am lacking one part to accomplish it.  phpVirtualBox requires you to edit the config.php file and change the password.
The section I am trying to modify is:

```
/* Username / Password for system user that runs VirtualBox */

var $username = 'vbox';<br>
var $password = 'pass'; **********This Line*****************
```

I've read (man sed) and looked all over the internet for a solution, no luck.

I have tried multiple sed commands but none will insert the ' tick marks.

I was able to get everything except the (').
These marks need to surround the password to make the config.php file work properly.

I am able to delete the entire line then trying to insert a new line only inserts:

```
var $password = pass ;
```

Can anyone please help me figure out how to insert the full line:

```
var $password 'pass';
```

I'll post the full script is anyone is interested in using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the '' unchanged and replace the value inside:

```
echo "var \$password = 'pass';" | sed "s@'pass'@'newpass'@"
```

Result

```
var $password = 'newpass';
```

Comment: echo "var \$password='pass';" | sed "s@'pass'@'newpass'@" config.php > config.php1.   This created the file i wanted with the change i needed.  then delete the original and rename config.php1 to config.php.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "var \$password = 'pass';"|sed "s/\(var \$password = '\)[^']\+';/\1changed_pass\';/g"
```

It match the content `var $password= 'sometext';` and keep the `var $password= '`as `\1`,put your new password next to `\1` and then add the left part `';`

Comment: Hello, you might want to add some explanation about why your proposed solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Just use sed this way:

**on Mac OS X:**

```
sed -i '' "s/var $password =.*/var $password = 'newpass'/" ~/yourscript.sh
```

**on Ubuntu:**

```
sed -i "s/var $password =.*/var $password = 'newpass'/" ~/yourscript.sh
```

*Yourscript is just the file containing the configuration that you want to override, in this case the one containing the password attribute*

I hope you find this answer helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: hope just that password does not contain meta character (sed POV)